# UIPickerView Multiple rows display in UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am trying to display my UIPickerView in a TextField, I have done it so it displays one of the rows but not all of them.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

static var isAlreadyLaunchedOnce = false
var ref: DatabaseReference!


    @IBOutlet weak var txtDate: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var inputpickerdate: UIPickerView!



    var pickerDate: [[String]] = [[String]] ()


    var selected: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.inputpickerdate.delegate = self
    self.inputpickerdate.dataSource = self

        pickerDate = [["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"], ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"], ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]]

        if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }



}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 3

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            //return pickerList.count
        return pickerDate [component].count

        }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return pickerDate [component] [row]

   }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        txtDate.text = pickerDate[component][row]
        self.view.endEditing(false)

    }

    }
```

In the textview I only see the month not the full date, I want to show something like:

mon day year

Not sure how to do this, basically needs to show all rows not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are are setting the text in your `UITextField` only to the text of the component you are selecting `pickerDate[component][row]`.

There are multiple ways you could achieve what you want to do with a UIPicker, albeit quite convoluted...

e.g.

- You could have three labels, one for each component.
- You could persist the selection of each component, then build up a string from the persisted values.

A much better way to pick dates would be to use a `UIDatePicker` instead.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var datepicker: UIDatePicker!

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        datepicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func dateChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        txtDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }
}
```

If you do want to go down the route of using a `UIPickerView` you could persist the value of each component and use those values to build up the string you want to display.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    let pickerData: [[String]] = [
        ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
        ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"],
        ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    ]

    var weekDay: String = ""
    var dayOfMonth: String = ""
    var month: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.dataSource = self

        // Give the label a default value
        weekDay = pickerData[0][0]
        dayOfMonth = pickerData[1][0]
        month = pickerData[2][0]

        updateDateText()
    }

    func updateDateText() {
        txtDate.text = "\(weekDay) \(dayOfMonth) \(month)"
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData [component].count
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[component][row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        switch component {
        case 0:
            weekDay = pickerData[component][row]
        case 1:
            dayOfMonth = pickerData[component][row]
        case 2:
            month = pickerData[component][row]
        default:
            break
        }

        updateDateText()
    }
}
```

Comment: Im quite confused, could you explain this in more detail please.

Comment: @Wmwm19 have you tried with the date picker? Or do you need detail on how to do this with UIPickerView. If you are using dates I would strongly recommend the UIDatePicker

Comment: @Wmwm19 added an example of how you can do this with `UIPicker` if you wish

Comment: No the date picker has not go the days of the week, which is what I need to show. For example Monday, 1 March . etc .

Comment: @Wmwm19 Ok, in that case, the only way to include the day of the week is to use the `datepicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime` but I am guessing you don't want time within the picker? Take a look at the implementation using `UIPickerView` in the answer, you are going to have to use something like that if you want a date picker with the weekday component and no time comopnent.

Comment: Getting error Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range: 

on the line  weekDay = pickerDate[0][0]

Comment: @Wmwm19 make sure you have set the value of `pickerDate` before that line. In my example I have given `pickerData` a default value

Comment: Yes, fixed the problem. Thank you this works will + you answer

Comment: @Wmwm19 please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @Wmwm19 It doesn't appear to be accepted? Did you accept or upvote?

Comment: Hi, I have another question, I'm trying to apply this to multiple text fields and multiple pickerViews. Is this possible?

Comment: Also is it possible for the app to know what the actual date is?

Comment: @Wmwm19 look at `NSDateFormatter` & `NSDateComponents`